# Split row into multiple rows based on time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, common-table-expression, window-functions

Suppose in Oracle 10g, I have a table like this:

```
id    | start_date | end_date   | value   | parent_id
----------------------------------------------------
1     | 01-01-2001 | 01-01-2002 | aaaaaa  | 3
2     | 01-01-2003 | 01-01-2004 | bbbbbb  | 3
3     | 01-01-2000 | 01-01-2005 | cccccc  | 4
4     | 01-01-1999 | 01-01-2006 | dddddd  |null
```

I would like to see any gaps in be filled by the parent without overlap. More concretely the result should be something like:

```
start_date | end_date   | value  | depth 
-----------------------------------------
01-01-1999 | 01-01-2000 | dddddd | 2
01-01-2000 | 01-01-2001 | cccccc | 1
01-01-2001 | 01-01-2002 | aaaaaa | 0
01-01-2002 | 01-01-2003 | cccccc | 1
01-01-2003 | 01-01-2004 | bbbbbb | 0
01-01-2004 | 01-01-2005 | cccccc | 1
01-01-2005 | 01-01-2006 | dddddd | 2
```

The depth is the number of parents to get to the value but can be more then 2, so it would be best to use recursion.

You can assume that there is no overlap for the periods that have the same parent. All this without using stored procedures but feel free to bring CTEs, window functions, etc.

Comment: One of the main problems with your requirement is your definition of `depth`.  In order to calculate the `depth` of one particular row, you'd have to navigate all children to see how many levels exist. Very expensive.  It would be much better if you had it the other way around. That is, that `dddddd` is depth `0`, `cccccc` is depth `1`, and `aaaaaa` and `bbbbbb` are depth `2`.

Comment: @sstan, the definition of depth can be the other way around if you like. In other words, feel free to start from the parents instead of the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Don't know how well it will perform though.

The query is divided in 3 main CTEs:

1. A CTE to generate the desired date ranges for output purposes
2. A CTE to calculate the max depth in the tree
3. A CTE to join all the data together and flag the more "desirable" rows by depth using the `row_number()` window function.

Query:

```
with date_ranges_cte as (
  select add_months(date '1999-01-01', (rownum-1) * 12) as start_date,
         add_months(date '1999-01-01', rownum * 12) as end_date
    from dual
  connect by rownum <= 7
), max_level_cte as (
  select max(level) as max_level
    from tbl
   start with parent_id is null
 connect by prior id = parent_id
), main_cte as (
  select d.start_date, 
         d.end_date,
         t.value,
         t.lvl,
         row_number() over (partition by d.start_date, d.end_date order by t.lvl desc, t.id) as rn
    from date_ranges_cte d
    join (select t.*, level as lvl
            from tbl t
           start with parent_id is null
         connect by prior id = parent_id) t
      on ((d.start_date >= t.start_date and d.start_date < t.end_date)
          or (d.end_date > t.start_date and d.end_date <= t.end_date))
)
select m.start_date,
       m.end_date,
       m.value,
       l.max_level - m.lvl as depth
  from main_cte m
  cross join max_level_cte l
 where m.rn = 1
 order by m.start_date
```

If you're ok reversing the definition of `depth`, then we can get rid of one of the CTEs:

```
with date_ranges_cte as (
  select add_months(date '1999-01-01', (rownum-1) * 12) as start_date,
         add_months(date '1999-01-01', rownum * 12) as end_date
    from dual
  connect by rownum <= 7
), main_cte as (
  select d.start_date, 
         d.end_date,
         t.value,
         t.lvl,
         row_number() over (partition by d.start_date, d.end_date order by t.lvl desc, t.id) as rn
    from date_ranges_cte d
    join (select t.*, level as lvl
            from tbl t
           start with parent_id is null
         connect by prior id = parent_id) t
      on ((d.start_date >= t.start_date and d.start_date < t.end_date)
          or (d.end_date > t.start_date and d.end_date <= t.end_date))
)
select start_date,
       end_date,
       value,
       lvl - 1 as depth
  from main_cte
 where rn = 1
 order by start_date
```

Comment: I tip my hat to you, sir. I'll need some time to learn what you have shown me, but a first test shows this does exactly what I need.

Comment: No problem.  If you break the query down into its smaller components and run them individually, I'm sure you'll be able to figure out how it works.